# Using a for loop to set attributes of a list of objects in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tkinter, config

I've written a Python program and I need to toggle a group of tkinter widgets from enabled to disabled and back again.  I could do it like this...

```
deadparrotlabel.config(state=DISABLED)
sillywalkslabel.config(state=DISABLED)
vikingslabel.config(state=DISABLED)
dinsdalelabel.config(state=DISABLED)
antpoetrylabel.config(state=DISABLED)
lumberjacklabel.config(state=DISABLED)
nudgenudgelabel.config(state=DISABLED)
saynomorelabel.config(state=DISABLED)
crunchyfroglabel.config(state=DISABLED)
larksvomitlabel.config(state=DISABLED)
```

but I get the feeling there should be a more efficient way, with a for loop and a list or something.  I just don't know how to get it to work or even if it can be done.  This is what I tried but it didn't work:

```
labellist = ['deadparrotlabel', 'sillywalkslabel', 'vikingslabel', 'dinsdalelabel', 'antpoetrylabel', 'lumberjacklabel', 'nudgenudgelabel', 'saynomorelabel', 'crunchyfroglabel', 'larksvomitlabel']
for i in lablelist:
    i.config(state=DISABLED)
```

Python interprets 'i' as a string instead of the name of an object.  Am I trying to do the impossible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a list of the widgets themselves:

```
widgets = [deadparrotlabel, sillywalkslabel, ... ]
for w in widgets:
    w.config(state=DISABLED)
```

Comment: Thank you, for the fast reply.  It seems so obvious now!  Leaving out the quote marks worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think Ned's is the correct answer, however, in general, if you *really* do have a string, and not an object that can be used, then:

```
widgets = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for w in widgets:
    globals()[w].config(state=DISABLED)
```

But then, be very wary if you find a need for this - as something has most likely gone wrong in your design process...

On an aside - perhaps `locals()` would be better - but difficult to tell...

Comment: Why provide answers like this??  Q: "How can I set fire to my entire house?"  A: "You probably don't want to, but gasoline works really well..."

Comment: @NedBatchelder as it turns out - it's purely redundant - but was a valid answer at the point of asking (with appropriate warning).

Comment: @NedBatchelder And why the internet is great for asking things, but able to remaining thankful I'll never meet these people: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100503200027AAc6DNi

Comment: @JonClements: In Tkinter when you have a widget by name, then you use the method `nametowidget` present in any `Tk()` instance. Ned`s answer is actually a quick comment that says "remove commas", too bad it was promptly accepted. But, please, update your answer to consider `nametowidget`.